# C++ library for renaming/moving/organizing files

Tags: c++, file, io, libraries, directory

I have a bunch of .mp3 files with really lousy names, and im looking to write a program that can rename each and every one into a legitamate recognizing name. I am looking for a library that could

1. get the name of a mp3 file, and rename that file
2. create new directories, and move certain files

If anyone knows a good library to use, or if C++ already has it built in, let me know please!

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 6):

Give Boost Filesystem http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/filesystem/index.html a try.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using [Boost.Filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/filesystem/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

`rename()` is in the standard library.

For most of the rest, consider Boost [Filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/index.htm).

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would use [boost::filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/index.htm).

Answer (score 0):

boost::filesystem seems like the winner, but QDir and QFile are pretty nice too. I've been happy with how Qt does things in a platform invisible (to me) way. If you don't want to check out boost for some reason, you may want to consider Qt.

I'm not saying anything negative about boost, I just figured this might be a helpful alternative.